# Difference of refractive indices of fiber layer

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

recently I received a simulation related document from a fiber manufacturer.

The simulated fiber has an inner core, outer core and a cladding.
The strange thing about the document is, that in the document only the differences of the refractive indices (n3-n2; n2-n1) are used, instead of the the rates of the refractive indices (n3/n2; n2/n1).

Could someone explain me why would a manufacturer use differences of refractive indices in their simulations? Is there any manufacturing process/calculation which needs/uses these differences?

Secrecy cannot be the reason, as the manufacturer did disclose that the cladding is pure silica, so all other indices can be calculated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dunno, other than that Snell's Law and its prediction of TIR (total internal reflection) depends only on those ratios and not the absolute values.

Answer (score 2):

Such fibers are waveguides which work as photonic crystals, that is, periodic structures with alternating layers of dielectrics. Photonic crystals have stopbands, i.e. spectral regions where the reflectance is high (and transmittance is low). These stopbands allow the waveguide to keep the light inside and actually conduct it (not lose it due to scattering). Now, the bandwidth of these stopbands is directly proportional to the difference of the refractive indices of the constituting dielectrics (the higher the index contrast, the wider the stopband). As such, if one is interested in the spectral range where this particular waveguide is working, it is somewhat easier to determine it from the difference of the indices, rather than the indices themselves or their ratio. So in the end it's a matter of convenience.

Of course, I'm not 100% sure that this is the only reason here.

Comment: This is a bit of a stretch to use the term "photonic crystal," since the optical fiber layers are not crystalline, and it's really just a simple (!!) case of TIR

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you do know how optical reflectivity works in photonic crystal waveguides, don't you?

Comment: thank you for you input